# NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.lucene.document.Field

Tags: java, eclipse, lucene, jena

I have another project, jena full text search too, but i got errors in runtime. The errors show below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.lucene.document.Field.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/lucene/index/IndexableFieldType;)V
at org.apache.jena.query.text.TextIndexLucene.doc(TextIndexLucene.java:347)
at org.apache.jena.query.text.TextIndexLucene.addDocument(TextIndexLucene.java:308)
at org.apache.jena.query.text.TextIndexLucene.addEntity(TextIndexLucene.java:300)
at org.apache.jena.query.text.TextDocProducerTriples.change(TextDocProducerTriples.java:71)
at org.apache.jena.sparql.core.DatasetGraphMonitor.record(DatasetGraphMonitor.java:194)
at org.apache.jena.sparql.core.DatasetGraphMonitor.add$(DatasetGraphMonitor.java:114)
at org.apache.jena.sparql.core.DatasetGraphMonitor.add(DatasetGraphMonitor.java:108)
at org.apache.jena.sparql.core.GraphView.performAdd(GraphView.java:149)
at org.apache.jena.graph.impl.GraphBase.add(GraphBase.java:184)
at org.apache.jena.riot.system.StreamRDFLib$ParserOutputGraph.triple(StreamRDFLib.java:181)
at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangTurtle.emit(LangTurtle.java:57)
at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangTurtleBase.emitTriple(LangTurtleBase.java:486)
at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangTurtleBase.objectList(LangTurtleBase.java:352)
at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangTurtleBase.predicateObjectItem(LangTurtleBase.java:288)
at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangTurtleBase.predicateObjectList(LangTurtleBase.java:269)
at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangTurtleBase.triples(LangTurtleBase.java:250)
at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangTurtleBase.triplesSameSubject(LangTurtleBase.java:191)
at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangTurtle.oneTopLevelElement(LangTurtle.java:46)
at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangTurtleBase.runParser(LangTurtleBase.java:91)
at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangBase.parse(LangBase.java:41)
at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFParserRegistry$ReaderRIOTLang.read(RDFParserRegistry.java:191)
at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFParser.read(RDFParser.java:352)
at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFParser.parseURI(RDFParser.java:321)
at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFParser.parse(RDFParser.java:295)
at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFParserBuilder.parse(RDFParserBuilder.java:506)
at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.parseFromURI(RDFDataMgr.java:890)
at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.read(RDFDataMgr.java:221)
at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.read(RDFDataMgr.java:102)
at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.read(RDFDataMgr.java:93)
at main.Search.loadData(Search.java:103)
at main.Search.main(Search.java:50)
```

I try to include `org.apache.lucene.document.Field` in my Lucene Lib but it doesn't work. I think it may be a problem in `loadData` in my codes. The full codes in below:

```
public class Search {
static String URI = "http://www.tutorialacademy.com/jenatext#";

static {LogCtl.setLog4j();
BasicConfigurator.configure();} 
static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger("Search");

public static void main(String ... argv)
{
    TextQuery.init();
    Dataset ds = createIndexedDataset("tdb", "luceneindex", "hasLongText");
    loadData(ds, "res/data2.ttl");
    queryData(ds);

}

public static Dataset createIndexedDataset(String tdbPath, String lucenePath, String indexedProperty)
{
    Dataset graphDS = null;

    if(tdbPath == null)
    {
        System.out.println("Construct an in-memory dataset");
        graphDS = DatasetFactory.createMem();
    }else
    {
        System.out.println("Construct a persistant TDB based dataset to: " + tdbPath);
        graphDS = DatasetFactory.create();
    }
    //define the index mapping
    EntityDefinition entDef = new EntityDefinition ("uri", "text", ResourceFactory.createProperty(URI, indexedProperty));
    Directory luceneDir = null;

    // check for in memory or file based (persistant) index
    if (lucenePath == null)
    {
        System.out.println("Construct an in-memory lucene index");
        luceneDir = new RAMDirectory();
    }else
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Construct a persistant lucene index to: " + lucenePath);
            luceneDir = new SimpleFSDirectory(Paths.get(lucenePath));
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //create new indexed dataset: insert operations are automatically indexed with lucene
    Dataset ds = TextDatasetFactory.createLucene(graphDS, luceneDir,  new TextIndexConfig(entDef));
    return ds;
}

public static void loadData(Dataset dataset, String file)
{
    System.out.println("Load data...");
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    dataset.begin(ReadWrite.WRITE);
    try
    {
        Model m = dataset.getDefaultModel();
        RDFDataMgr.read(m, file);
        dataset.commit();
    }
    finally
    {
        dataset.end();
    }

    long finishTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long time = finishTime - startTime;
    System.out.println("Loading finished after "+ time+ " ms");
}

public static void queryData(Dataset dataset)
{
    System.out.println("Query data...");
    String prefix = "PREFIX ta: <" + URI + ">"+
                                    "PREFIX text: <http://jena.apache.org/text#>";
    String query = "SELECT * WHERE" +
                                    "{ ?s text:query (ta:hasLongText 'g?eat')."+
                                    " ?s ta.hasLongText ?text . "+
                                    "}";

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    dataset.begin(ReadWrite.READ);
    try
    {
        Query q = QueryFactory.create(prefix + query);
        QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(q,dataset);
        QueryExecUtils.executeQuery(q, qexec);
    }
    finally
    {
        dataset.end();
    }

    long finishTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    long time = finishTime- startTime;
    System.out.println("Query finished after " + time +" ms.");
}}
```

May i get some advise? Thank you

Comment: Try doing a clean build of your project and give a try again .. You could even check the jar and may be tweak the application by removing the jar file and see if the expected jar is being reference... Also What version of Lucene are you using. I am not familiar with Lucene but similar errors could be local to one particular version and could be a known issue fixed in future versions .. Why dont you try with a different version ?

Comment: @parthi i've degraded the version of Lucene into 6.4.0. thanks for the helps!

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd guess you have Lucene version 8.0 or later, which it doesn't look like Jena supports yet.  Make sure you are using the correct version of lucene for whatever version of Jena you have: https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/text-query.html

Comment: i never pay attention of that. i degraded to Lucene 6.4.0 and it works. thanks for the helps!